# Did medieval ransom taking have agents?

Tags: middle-ages, prisoners-of-war

[Medieval ransom taking](https://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/history/european-history-1000-1450/prisoners-war-hundred-years-war-ransom-culture-late-middle-ages) was big- people were taken of all types of social standing for wide ranges of payments for their release- virtually a business. Did the business have agents who provide various services including taking care of the ransomed person and handling the payments?

Comment: This is tagged crime. Historically, ransom was what one did to **prisoners as war**, a condition of their release.

Comment: Which kind of captives? In Southern Europe there were some religious orders (like the [Mercedarians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_the_Blessed_Virgin_Mary_of_Mercy)) who collected donations to buy back into freedom Christians enslaved by the Muslims, and I have heard some vague references to the Muslims establishing a similar schema, but your link references the Hundred Years War.

Comment: What do you suggest I tag it with? It is a crime in one place and in the law in the other.

Comment: There are "slavery", "prisoners-of-war" tags. You could also use tags to further limit the question ("Middle-Ages" includes up to a millenia in more than a continent), so tags like "Western Europe" or "Hundred Years Wars" might come in handy.